# Can't get mapview V2 to show

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I'm struggling get a mapview inside the app I am developing.
I have successfully generated an API key in the google console, and added the permission to the manifest and check logcat for some failures but nothing.

Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_box_container2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minWidth="450dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/geo_map_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/distribuzione_title"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.previnet.mobile.dashboard.credem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="it.previnet.mobile.dashboard.credem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="it.previnet.mobile.dashboard.credem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_credemvita"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDfFnshaZgWuun842Z3wzGN4gqp2dj98ew" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here the code:

```
protected void initMap(View geo) {
    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) geo.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(43.1, -87.9);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9)).title("Marker"));
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, the problem wasn't the map but the textview above. Changed layout_height to wrap_content ad know i can see the MapView

Answer (score 1):

why you set all parameters height match_parent???

I suggest this code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_box_container2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minWidth="450dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/geo_map_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/distribuzione_title"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```